# .htaccess file on xampp (basedir wrong.. incorrect path for images, css files..)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

i got another problem.

i have an own apache server (XAMPP) on my computer. The URL in my browser looks like

```
http://localhost/pageExample/index.php
```

i use a .**htaccess** file to change my url **from** `?action=home` **to** `home.html`

The problem now is, that the path to all images, css files etc be wrong. They looks like

```
http://localhost/images/logo.jpg
```

I think, there is something wrong in my .htaccess file... i tried `<base href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/pageExample/">`.. this works ..okay... but some scripts with extern images doesnt work.

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home.html$ /pageExample/index.php?action=home [L]
```

(By the way... the problem came since I created the .htaccess)

How to change this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when you start rewriting URLs but website is not coded accordingly. In your HTML/CSS, when you are referring to images/scripts/css resources you most likely have something like this: `<img src="images/hello.jpg" />`. Bacuse you are rewriting URLs you need to alter the resource URLs as well -- in the above example resource is linked to the path of the HTML file (relative path) -- you need to make the path **absolute**. For this -- add leading slash before resource references:

change

`<img src="images/hello.jpg" />`

to

`<img src="/images/hello.jpg" />`